# Нарисовать пустой двойной ромб

Tags: javascript, консоль, символы, рисование

Подскажите пжл как нарисовать двойной пустой ромб. Сам ромб я реализовал, но не пойму как сделать его двойным.

[image: Двойной ромб]

```
function printMirror(n) {
    let i, j;
    let str = '';
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        for (j = n; j > i; j--) {
            str += ' ';
        }
        str += '*';
        for (j = 1; j < (i - 1) * 2; j++) {
            str += ' ';
        }
        if (i == 1) {
            str += ('\n');
        } else {
            str += ('*\n');
        }
    }
    for (i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
        for (j = 1; j < i; j++) {
            str += " ";
        }

        for (j = 1; j <= n * 2 - (2 * i - 1); j++) {

            if (i == 0 || j == 1 || j == n * 2 - (2 * i - 1)) {
                str += "*";
            } else {
                str += " ";
            }

        }
        str += "\n";
    }
    return '`\n' + str + '`';
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это можно было бы делать "чистыми" for... но показалось легче немного поиграть с массивами.

```js
let demo = document.getElementById('demo');

demo.value = printMirror(6, 3, 3); // 6 "этажей", 3 ромбика, по 3 пробела между ними

function printMirror(n, qty, space) {
  space = space ? multiplyStr(" ", space) : "";
  
  let strs = []; // Будем собирать все строчки в массив
  for( let i = 0; i < n; i++ ){
    let str = "";
    for( let j = n; j >= 0; j-- ){ // Обратный перебор, чтобы в конце был один reverse
      str += ( j == i ) ? "*" : " "; // Можно поставить и 2-3 пробела - будет "толще"
    } 
    // Один раз пробежались и усё - уже есть основная "лесенка" из звездочек.
    // Всё остальное можно строить на её основе.
    
    str += str.split("").reverse().slice(1).join("");
    // Перевернули, убрали один символ, результат добавили к начальной строке. Было
    
    //      *                 *
    //     *      станет     * *
    //    *                 *   *
    
    let s = str;
    for( let j = 1; j < qty; j++ ){
      str += space + s;
      /* Повторяем еще qty-1 раз, вставляя между ними нужное кол-во пробелов */
    }
    
    strs.push(str); // Сохраняем каждую готовую строку в массиве
  }
  
  return '`\n' + strs.join('\n') + '\n' + strs.reverse().slice(1).join('\n') + '\n`';
}

function multiplyStr(str, qty){
  let x = "";
  for( let i = 0; i < qty; i++ ){
    x += str;
  }
  return x;
}


/***** Кусок Демо *****/

let n = document.getElementById('n');
let qty = document.getElementById('qty');
let space = document.getElementById('space');

document.getElementById('print').addEventListener('click', function(){
  demo.value = printMirror(n.value || 5, qty.value, space.value);
});
```

```css
#demo {  
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  padding-top: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: pre;
}

.menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 5px;
  right: 20px;
}

input { width: 40px; text-align: center; }
```

```html
<textarea id="demo"></textarea>
<div class="menu">
  <button id="print">printMirror</button> (
  <input id="n" placeholder="n">, 
  <input id="qty" placeholder="qty">, 
  <input id="space" placeholder="space">)
</div>
```

P.S. если соберетесь вставить это куда-нибудь в textarea - надо дать ему `overflow-x: auto; white-space: pre;` — чтобы всё не испортилось, если экран окажется меньше, чем длина строк.

Answer (score 3):

Представим себе *координатную плоскость* и нарисуем график функции в виде ромба:

```js
Math.abs(y - n) + Math.abs(x - n) == n
```

Точка *ноль* находится в верхнем левом углу, а оси направлены вниз и вправо:

```js
// размер ромба
let n = 6;
// количество ромбов
let m = 4;
// вертикальная ось
for (let y = 0; y <= 2 * n; y++) {
  // строка символов
  let line = '';
  // горизонтальная ось
  for (let x = 0; x < 2 * n * m + m; x++) {
    // текущий ромб
    let k = Math.trunc(x / (2 * n + 1));
    // центр ромба
    let c = Math.trunc((2 * k + 1) * n + k);
    // если точка принадлежит ромбу
    if (Math.abs(y - n) + Math.abs(x - c) == n)
      line += '*';
    else
      line += ' ';
  }
  // выводим строку
  console.log(line);
}
```

Вывод:

```
      *            *            *            *      
     * *          * *          * *          * *     
    *   *        *   *        *   *        *   *    
   *     *      *     *      *     *      *     *   
  *       *    *       *    *       *    *       *  
 *         *  *         *  *         *  *         * 
*           **           **           **           *
 *         *  *         *  *         *  *         * 
  *       *    *       *    *       *    *       *  
   *     *      *     *      *     *      *     *   
    *   *        *   *        *   *        *   *    
     * *          * *          * *          * *     
      *            *            *            *
```

---

<sup>См. [How to draw a double empty ASCII rhombus?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68155637/16596785)</sup>