# Как нарисовать ромб на JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, консоль, символы, рисование

у меня не получается

```js
var space = 18;
var star = 1;
var line = 20;
for (var i = 0; i <= line; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j <= space; j++) {
    document.write("&nbsp")
  }
  for (var k = 0; k < star; k++) {
    document.write("*")
  }
  space--;
  star++;
  if (i === line / 2 && i <= line) {
    for (var rev = line; rev >= line / 2; i++) {
      space++;
      star--;
    }
  }
  document.write("<br>");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Два вложенных цикла от `-h` до `h`. Нулевая точка расположена в центре фигуры.

Форма ромба получается, когда:

```js
Math.abs(i) + Math.abs(j) == h
```

JavaScript:

```js
// размер ромба
let h = 5;
// вертикальная ось
for (let i = -h; i <= h; i++) {
  // строка символов
  let line = '';
  // горизонтальная ось
  for (let j = -h; j <= h; j++) {
    // когда точка принадлежит ромбу
    if (Math.abs(i) + Math.abs(j) == h) {
      line += 'Ж';
    } else {
      line += '*';
    }
  }
  // выводим строку
  console.log(line);
}
```

Вывод:

```
*****Ж*****
****Ж*Ж****
***Ж***Ж***
**Ж*****Ж**
*Ж*******Ж*
Ж*********Ж
*Ж*******Ж*
**Ж*****Ж**
***Ж***Ж***
****Ж*Ж****
*****Ж*****
```

---

<sup>См. [Нарисовать пустой двойной ромб](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1316500/456254)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Этот цикл никогда не завершится, и программа ничего не нарисует.

```
for (var rev = line; rev >= line / 2; i++) {
  space++;
  star--;
}
```

Comment: ну тогда как мне сделать это ?

Comment: @Slow Молодец. Желаю дальнейших успехов!

Answer (score 1):

```js
var space = 18;
var star = 1;
var line = 20;
for (var i = 0; i <= line; i++){
    for (var j = 0; j <= space; j++){
        document.write("&nbsp")
    }
    for (var k = 0; k < star; k++){
        document.write("*")
    }
    space--;
    star++;
    if (i >= line / 2 && i <= line){
        star = star - 2;
        space = space + 2;
    }
    document.write("<br>");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
n = 11
document.body.textContent = 
  Array(n).fill().map((x, i) => "*".repeat(2*Math.min(i,n-1-i)+1)).join("\n")
```

```css
body { font-family: monospace; white-space: pre; text-align: center; }
```

Comment: а два ромба рядом? :)

Comment: @Grundy, display: flex ;)